# Почему jquery не видит изменения в разметке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

Делаю аякс запрос, после которого меня значение атрибута. В DOM всё меняется, как положено. Но когда снова кликаю по кнопке - в консоль выводится старое значение аттрибута. Такое ощущение, что не видит изменения в разметке и подгружает старые данные.

```js
$('.more_credits_first').click(function () {
 var button = $(this)
 var show = $(button).data('show');
 console.log(show)

 if (show == 'show') {
  $.get(window.location.pathname,{}).done(function(data){
   $('.tbody.main_credits').append(data.template);
   $(button).attr('data-show', 'hide');
   $(button).text('Скрыть');
  })
 } else {
  $(this).attr('data-show', 'show');
  $(this).text('Ещё кредиты');
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='more_credits_first' type="button" data-show='show'>Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: data-show'='show' полагаю что ошибка в лишней кавычке

Comment: нет, это я ошибся, когда код здесь писал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно редактировать html-атрибут, редактируйте dataset.

Т.е. вместо `$(button).attr('data-show', 'hide');` нужно:

```
button.data('show', 'hide');
```

И то же самое для установки значения 'show':

```
button.data('show', 'show');
```